# Difference between Matlab and Eigen results while using the SVD method

Tags: c++, matlab, linear-algebra, eigen3, svd

I'm trying to refactor a Direct Linear Transform algorithm that was previously written in Matlab into C++.
While comparing the resulting matrices from performing a SVD on my matrix **A**, I noticed a big value difference in some elements of the resulting right singular matrix **V**.

Precisely I'm interested in taking the vector that corresponds to the smallest singular value (which should be found in the last column of matrix V as is the case in Matlab), but the values in rightmost columns of the Eigen matrix **V** differ greatly from Matlab's **V**. I also noticed a sign difference between the values but I know that comes from SVD having multiple solutions for different sign values of **U** and **V** matrices.

Here is the matrix **A** on which I'm performing the SVD:

```
Matrix -A
   1    1    1    1   -0   -0   -0   -0   -1   -1   -1   -1
  -0   -0   -0   -0    1    1    1    1   -1   -1   -1   -1
   2    2    2    1   -0   -0   -0   -0   -4   -4   -4   -2
  -0   -0   -0   -0    2    2    2    1   -4   -4   -4   -2
   3    3    3    1   -0   -0   -0   -0   -9   -9   -9   -3
  -0   -0   -0   -0    3    3    3    1   -9   -9   -9   -3
   4    4    4    1   -0   -0   -0   -0  -16  -16  -16   -4
  -0   -0   -0   -0    4    4    4    1  -16  -16  -16   -4
   5    5    5    1   -0   -0   -0   -0  -25  -25  -25   -5
  -0   -0   -0   -0    5    5    5    1  -25  -25  -25   -5
   6    6    6    1   -0   -0   -0   -0  -36  -36  -36   -6
  -0   -0   -0   -0    6    6    6    1  -36  -36  -36   -6
   7    7    7    1   -0   -0   -0   -0  -49  -49  -49   -7
  -0   -0   -0   -0    7    7    7    1  -49  -49  -49   -7
   8    8    8    1   -0   -0   -0   -0  -64  -64  -64   -8
  -0   -0   -0   -0    8    8    8    1  -64  -64  -64   -8
   9    9    9    1   -0   -0   -0   -0  -81  -81  -81   -9
  -0   -0   -0   -0    9    9    9    1  -81  -81  -81   -9
  10   10   10    1   -0   -0   -0   -0 -100 -100 -100  -10
  -0   -0   -0   -0   10   10   10    1 -100 -100 -100  -10
```

Matlab code:

```
[U,S, V] = svd(A);

disp('Singular Values S:');
disp(S);


disp('Matrix V:');
disp(V);

disp(U*S*V');
```

C++ code:

```
Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd> svd;

//svd.setThreshold(1e-10);

svd.compute(A, Eigen::ComputeFullU | Eigen::ComputeFullV);

Eigen::VectorXd singularValues = svd.singularValues();
Eigen::MatrixXd singularValueMatrix = singularValues.asDiagonal();

int dimensionDiff = A.cols() - A.rows();

if (dimensionDiff <= 0) { //Formatting the singular value matrix so that it matches Matlab's
    singularValueMatrix.conservativeResize(singularValueMatrix.rows() + -dimensionDiff, singularValueMatrix.cols() );

    for (size_t i = 1; i <= -dimensionDiff; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < singularValueMatrix.cols(); j++)
        {
            singularValueMatrix(singularValueMatrix.rows()-i,j) = 0;
        }
    }
}
else {
    singularValueMatrix.conservativeResize(singularValueMatrix.rows(), singularValueMatrix.cols() + dimensionDiff);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < singularValueMatrix.rows()-1; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 1; j < dimensionDiff; j++)
        {
            singularValueMatrix(i, singularValueMatrix.cols() - j) = 0;
        }
    }
}



Eigen::MatrixXd U = svd.matrixU();
Eigen::MatrixXd V = svd.matrixV();

//Displaying the results

std::cout <<  "Singular Values:\n" << singularValueMatrix << "\n\n";
std::cout << "Left Singular Vectors (U):\n" << U << "\n\n";
std::cout << "Right Singular Vectors (V):\n" << V << "\n\n";

std::cout << "Reconstructed Matrix:\n" << U * singularValueMatrix * V.transpose() << std::endl;
```

As you can see in the C++ code, I tried setting the calculation threshold but that also didn't yield any different results.

Here are the results in C++:
[C++ SVD Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAdDb.png)

And here are the results in Matlab:
[Matlab SVD Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkzcu.png)

What I find interesting is that the reconstructed matrix **A** is equal to the input matrix **A** (except for some zeroes being replaced by garbage values), but the **V** matrices are different. Also, for square matrices the results from both C++ and Matlab match.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it because of the precision error while multiplying with the singular value matrix?

Comment: “I know that comes from SVD having multiple solutions” — this is likely the reason for all the differences you see. Given that the reconstructed matrix is correct, differences must come from ambiguities in the SVD for this particular matrix (== multiple possible solutions) and the two implementations picking different solutions.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for the comment. What I have gathered is that SVD solution is unique up to a sign change which means that the values themselves should be the same across both Eigen and Matlab with only the signs of the values differing.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3754529/414894

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ahh that clears it up, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What version of MATLAB are you running? Anyway, I tested following code in both MATLAB 2023b and Octave 8.3, Windows 10 x64. And they produce close enough but not identical V between themselves.

```
Z= [ 1    1    1    1   -0   -0   -0   -0   -1   -1   -1   -1; ...
    -0   -0   -0   -0    1    1    1    1   -1   -1   -1   -1; ...
     2    2    2    1   -0   -0   -0   -0   -4   -4   -4   -2; ...
    -0   -0   -0   -0    2    2    2    1   -4   -4   -4   -2; ...
     3    3    3    1   -0   -0   -0   -0   -9   -9   -9   -3; ...
    -0   -0   -0   -0    3    3    3    1   -9   -9   -9   -3; ...
     4    4    4    1   -0   -0   -0   -0  -16  -16  -16   -4; ...
    -0   -0   -0   -0    4    4    4    1  -16  -16  -16   -4; ...
     5    5    5    1   -0   -0   -0   -0  -25  -25  -25   -5; ...
    -0   -0   -0   -0    5    5    5    1  -25  -25  -25   -5; ...
     6    6    6    1   -0   -0   -0   -0  -36  -36  -36   -6; ...
    -0   -0   -0   -0    6    6    6    1  -36  -36  -36   -6; ...
     7    7    7    1   -0   -0   -0   -0  -49  -49  -49   -7; ...
    -0   -0   -0   -0    7    7    7    1  -49  -49  -49   -7; ...
     8    8    8    1   -0   -0   -0   -0  -64  -64  -64   -8; ...
    -0   -0   -0   -0    8    8    8    1  -64  -64  -64   -8; ...
     9    9    9    1   -0   -0   -0   -0  -81  -81  -81   -9; ...
    -0   -0   -0   -0    9    9    9    1  -81  -81  -81   -9; ...
    10   10   10    1   -0   -0   -0   -0 -100 -100 -100  -10; ...
    -0   -0   -0   -0   10   10   10    1 -100 -100 -100  -10];

format bank;
    
A = double(-Z);

disp('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');

[U, S, V] = svd(A);

disp(U*S*V');

disp('------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');

disp(V);
```

Octave V:

```
0.03   0.41  -0.31  -0.03  -0.05   0.01   0.55  -0.17   0.03  -0.02   0.63   0.00
0.03   0.41  -0.31  -0.03  -0.05   0.02  -0.38   0.56  -0.52   0.05   0.09  -0.00
0.03   0.41  -0.31  -0.03  -0.05  -0.02   0.36  -0.10   0.01   0.02  -0.77  -0.00
0.00   0.06  -0.12   0.70   0.70   0.00  -0.00   0.00   0.00  -0.00   0.00  -0.00
0.03  -0.41  -0.31   0.03  -0.05  -0.49   0.30   0.58   0.25  -0.04  -0.01   0.00
0.03  -0.41  -0.31   0.03  -0.05   0.25   0.12  -0.15  -0.36   0.05  -0.02   0.71
0.03  -0.41  -0.31   0.03  -0.05   0.25   0.12  -0.15  -0.36   0.05  -0.02  -0.71
0.00  -0.06  -0.12  -0.70   0.70  -0.00  -0.00  -0.00   0.00  -0.00   0.00  -0.00
-.57   0.00  -0.06   0.00  -0.01  -0.33  -0.05  -0.19  -0.25  -0.67  -0.01   0.00
-.57   0.00  -0.06   0.00  -0.01  -0.32  -0.04  -0.16  -0.08   0.73   0.03   0.00
-.57   0.00  -0.06  -0.00  -0.01   0.65   0.09   0.35   0.33  -0.05  -0.02  -0.00
-.07  -0.00   0.62  -0.00   0.11   0.01   0.54   0.29  -0.47   0.05  -0.05   0.00
```

MATLAB 2023b V:

```
      0.03          0.41          0.31         -0.03          0.05          0.84          0.02          0.00         -0.04          0.13          0.00          0.00         
      0.03          0.41          0.31         -0.03          0.05         -0.18         -0.07         -0.00          0.13         -0.83         -0.00          0.00
      0.03          0.41          0.31         -0.03          0.05         -0.39         -0.16          0.00         -0.67          0.32          0.00         -0.00
      0.00          0.06          0.12          0.70         -0.70          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00         -0.00          0.00         -0.00
      0.03         -0.41          0.31          0.03          0.05          0.10         -0.85         -0.00          0.03         -0.02          0.00          0.00
      0.03         -0.41          0.31          0.03          0.05          0.09          0.32          0.00         -0.31         -0.17          0.00          0.71
      0.03         -0.41          0.31          0.03          0.05          0.09          0.32          0.00         -0.31         -0.17         -0.00         -0.71
      0.00         -0.06          0.12         -0.70         -0.70          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00         -0.00          0.00         -0.00
     -0.57          0.00          0.06         -0.00          0.01         -0.00         -0.00          0.82          0.00          0.00          0.00         -0.00
     -0.57          0.00          0.06         -0.00          0.01         -0.00         -0.00         -0.41         -0.00          0.00         -0.71          0.00
     -0.57          0.00          0.06         -0.00          0.01         -0.00         -0.00         -0.41         -0.00          0.00          0.71          0.00
     -0.07         -0.00         -0.62         -0.00         -0.11          0.28         -0.21          0.00         -0.58         -0.37         -0.00          0.00
```

Comment: I am using the 2020 version of Matlab but it appears that the V matrix does not differ across Matlab versions. The answer probably boils down to the comment Cris wrote on the original question.

Comment: @plebs "it appears that the V matrix does not differ across Matlab versions" well, there is at least sign differences, check last column. Cris is probably right, there is not one definitive answer to SVD